# Is there a hitpoint limit?

Tags: skills, hit-points, rolemaster, middle-earth-role-playing

Is there a cap to how many hitpoints a character can develop in MERP, or can a character keep putting development points into body development out to eternity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can keep getting more hit points as long as you keep levelling.**
(MERP uses "hit points")

You've found a quirk of MERP from the conversion from Rolemaster that the designers didn't carry over "Racial maximum hit point" as a concept from Rolemaster.

In Rolemaster (1, 2, classic) a characters maximum hit points is determined by their race and their CON bonus; so a goblin might have a racial maximum of 80 hit points and a troll 200. The CON bonus gives a % extra on top of this, so a troll with 30 CON bonus would have 30% more than normal for their race. The race also determines which dice they roll for hit points for each rank of body development, whereas it's always a d10 in MERP.

However, in practice in MERP the number of hit points is self-limiting as the maximum number of body development ranks a character can have is limited by MERPs level cap of 10, and after that the system suggests using Rolemaster instead which has racial hit point caps.